# Comparing SQL Server DATETIME with DateTime.NOW in C# / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

How do I compare a SQL Server `DATETIME` with the `DateTime.Now` value? As you can see I assigned it to a Session and tried comparing it with `DateTime.Now`.

```
string timestamp = @"SELECT sr.*, ud.* FROM SuspensionRecord sr, UserData ud WHERE sr.User_ID=@User_ID AND ud.User_ID=@User_ID";

using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(timestamp, con))
{
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", Session["UserID"].ToString());

    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Session["suspensiondate"] = dr["End_Date_Suspension"].ToString();
            }

            if (Convert.ToDateTime(Session["supensiondate"]) >= DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "The account's status is suspended.";
                lblMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: And does your code not work?

Comment: May I suggest only selecting the necessary column instead of multiple .*'s in your initial query. There is no reason to pull back all that data if you are only using one column's data

Comment: Use a parameter of the proper type (see duplicate). Then just do a normal compare: `WHERE tblPrefix.DateColumn > @dateVariable`.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the line comparing session date with DateTime.Now. It should be `Session["suspensiondate"]` not `Session["supensiondate"]`.

Comment: @Igor - The dup doesn't look related to the question.  The one you linked to is about passing user input into a sql string, and using proper parameratized queries.  This one is more about properly using data that is returned from a query.   I see the problem here, is that the OP is abusing `.ToString()` and relying on parsing via `Convert.ToDateTime`, rather than casting to correct data types.

Comment: Yes it is working but not quite right even though my Session["suspensiondate"] is till December the client can still login which should not be what the system will do instead show the labels I declared

Comment: @LanceEbacuado - You should pass in the date and do the comparison in the query instead of in c#. That is one less step. If you do want to do it in c# then use the appropriate types, do not convert the DateTime to a string and then convert it back again.

Comment: @LanceEbacuado there is a typo in the if condition: `Session["supensiondate"]` should be `Session["suspensiondate"]`, although I don't know if the code has this typo too.

Comment: Also there is no need for the join (2nd table) in your query.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should pass in the date and do the comparison in the query instead of in c#. That is one less step. If you do want to do it in c# then use the appropriate types, do not convert the `DateTime` to a string and then convert it back again.
2. There is no need for the join (2nd table) in your query
3. You do not have to use a DataReader for this, you can use [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2) which returns 1 value instead.
4. Use `Add` so you can specify the correct schema types with [SqlDbType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=netframework-4.7.2) and not `AddWithValue`

```
string timestamp = @"SELECT 1 FROM SuspensionRecord sr WHERE sr.User_ID = @User_ID AND supensiondate > @now";
using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(timestamp, con))
{
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["UserID"]; // do not convert to string
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@now", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.Date;
    var result = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
    if(result != null) // if null then there were no records so account is not suspended
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "The account's status is suspended.";
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your schwartz is as big as mine :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled that comment alone deserves you an upvote.

Comment: And you got one for (hopefully) knowing where this quot is from :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, your SQL is terrible.
You are returning way too much data, and you are using an implicit join (when explicit joins are a part of ANSI-SQL for almost 30 years now!)

Second, [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Instead of all this code you can do the entire test on SQL and return a single value:

```
string sql = 
@"SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
  (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM SuspensionRecord 
      WHERE User_ID = @User_ID 
      AND End_Date_Suspension >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
  ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";
```

Then you can use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`, and you don't need to loop through all the irrelevant data:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(timestamp, con))
{
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["UserID"];
    if ((int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "The account's status is suspended.";
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
    }
}
```